# Does the bolt really rise upward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In [this site](http://irodovphysicssolutionrks.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/115.html?m=1),when the elevator rises up,the bolt falls downward under the force of gravity . But when distance is measured it is shown that it rises up,velocity becomes 0 & then it falls with respect to the shaft(earth) . One has asked the question in that site but the answer is not satisfactory. The bolt was falling downward so why in measuring distance, it rose up inspite of being  under the gravity? What is the cause? Plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Velocity plots of bolt in two frames of reference.

One: with respect to the floor/shaft. Elevator accelerates up and after two seconds it (and the bolt) has velocity of $2.4 m/s$. The bolt now breaks loose: it no longer experiences the upward force from the elevator, so it starts accelerating downwards - it will take about 1/4 of a second to lose its upward velocity ($2.4/9.8$), during which time it continues to move away from the floor. However relative to the elevator it is already dropping.

Two: with respect to the elevator car. The car stands still and the floor is accelerating away at $1.2 m/s^2$. After two seconds the bolt starts falling towards the floor with acceleration $g$. But the floor has a "head start" of two seconds. You can compute the distance from the top of the elevator to the floor as a function of time, and do your calculation that way.

Answer (score 3):

The elevator car, along with everything in it, is accelerating upwards. The bolt breaks free 2 seconds after the start of this upward acceleration. At that point in time when the bolt breaks free, it's velocity with respect to the elevator is the same as that as the elevator car. That velocity is of course upwards.

Comment: Velocity thus is forced to become $0$ and then accelerated in the direction of $g$ but i can't imagine when it rises up.

Comment: When it starts falling after 2 seconds, it goes downwards, so from the shaft, i will see the bolt going down. When or where will it rise?

Comment: @user36790 When the bolt jiggles loose or whatever happens to make it fall, it is travelling at that moment upwards with the same velocity as the elevator. Then gravity kicks in and it is accelerated downward at g. But the velocity of the bolt doesn't go to 0 immediately, that wouldn't make sense. Gravity decreases the upwards velocity before it can have a downwards velocity, but in the time it takes the bolt to go from the elevator's velocity at 2s to a velocity of 0, it must travel upwards because it has a decreasing but positive upwards velocity.

Comment: Sir,I ve understood ur explanation but will I really see it coming up during the fall(from lift, I'll see it coming down but the same thing when I see from the shaft it will go up)?

Comment: @user36790 Indeed